# How do I use @ConstructorBinding with child objects that only exist in lists?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to set up my application's Spring Cloud config objects using a Kotlin `data class`. I've been successful with using `@ConstructorBinding` when defining classes that exist once at a specific node in the config but have run into a roadblock with objects that only appear in a child list.

Sample config:

```yaml
toolbox:
  tools:
    - id: 1
      description: hammer
    - id: 2
      description: screwdriver
```

What I would like to be able to do is this:

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("toolbox")
data class ToolBox(val tools: List<Tool>) {

    @ConstructorBinding
    data class Tool (val id: String, val description: String)
}
```

But when I do this I receive errors like this:

```
Property: toolbox.tools[0].description
Value: hammer
Origin: "toolbox.tools[0].description" from property source "bootstrapProperties-https:/some-config.yml"
Reason: The elements [toolbox.tools[0].description,toolbox.tools[0].id,toolbox.tools[1].description,toolbox.tools[1].id] were left unbound.
```

My application is configured with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` and other uses of `@ConstructorBinding` work for me. For example, the following alternative configuration works:

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("toolbox")
data class ToolBox(val tools: List<Tool>) {

    class Tool {
        lateinit var id: String
        lateinit var description: String
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `@ConfigurationProperties` to the `Tool` class but that annotation requires a prefix and I don't know of a way to define a prefix that addresses into a list like I am trying to use here.

Is there a way to use `@ConstructorBinding` with a configuration class that only appears within a list?